# Unable to use NSURLRequest Xcode

Tags: xcode, nsurl

I am trying to call the following url in xcode

http://devsite.net/login.asp?longitude=-79 57 45.8153&latitude=40 23 29.8284&device=4FFB39E4-28A8-5E26-90C5-6E16105E08C8&username=spoilt&service=test&comments=T8a098098jjjal

the problem is when I try to do the following in xcode it does not appear to be working

```
NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:lsUrl]
                                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                          timeoutInterval:60.0];


    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

lsURL is the url from above.  Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here.  The url works when I type it into a web browser.

Comment: URL doesn't seem to be working for me(us) with space's. Anyway. What do you mean it doesn't work ? Have you implemented delegate methods for NSURLConnection ? If yes, whats the error you are getting and where.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to escape the spaces with %20?

http://www.december.com/html/spec/esccodes.html

Answer (score 0):

Step 1) Try creating an `NSURL` as a variable, using `lsUrl` as you do above.  Is that URL equal to `nil` ?  If so, you need to URL encode the string before you can make a URL from it.  Try using `[lsUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]` to get an encoded string.

Step 2) Have you implemented the methods described in the [NSURLConnectionDelegate protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSURLConnectionDelegate) in your class ?  Because you passed `self` as the delegate, the system expects your class to implement these methods, and the data that you're expecting will be delivered to those methods.

Step 3) Did you call `[conn start]` in your code ?  The code above just sets up the connection, but does not tell it to connect to the server.